# error LNK2005 not getting to solution to solve the problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hyperlink

i am new to C++ need some help on this

*mainclinet.CPP*

```
#include "client.h"
#include "config.h*"
int main(){
    g_pClientSampleConfig = new ClientSampleConfig;
    g_pUaSession = NULL;
    g_pCallback = NULL;
    g_nsIndex = OpcUa_UInt16_Max;
    g_nsIndex2 = OpcUa_UInt16_Max;

     client();

      }
```

function client() is declared in this files mainclient.CPP

*client.h*

```
    OpcUa_UInt16                            g_nsIndex2;
    ClientSampleConfig*                     g_pClientSampleConfig = NULL;
    UaSession*                              m_pSession;
    void Connection_Initialzation();
```

*config.cpp*

```
ClientSampleConfig::ClientSampleConfig()
 {
 //some code
 } 


ClientSampleConfig::~ClientSampleConfig()
 {
 }
```

*config.h*

```
   class ClientSampleConfig
{
public:
ClientSampleConfig();
~ClientSampleConfig(); 
}
```

the problem is i created a new file called clinet_start.cpp
in which i am defined the  client(); with return type void when i trying to include the clinet.h in clinet_start.cpp it's giving the linker Error 2005 *class UaClientSdk::UaSession * g_pUaSession"* redefined i need help in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Linker Tools Error LNK2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?view=vs-2019)

If `mainclinet.CPP` and `clinet_start.cpp` include `clinet.h` , then both are compiled with your definition of `client()`, so both object files will contain code for `client()`. When the linker gathers all the functions, he sees that `client()` is defined in two object files and does not know which one to use. Thus the linker raises an LNK2005.

There are two solutions for you:

1,If you want `client()` to be inlined, you could try to use [Inline Functions (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=vs-2019)

2,If you don't care about inlining, you could try to use [extern (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=vs-2019)